# How to dynamically set div size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div container with a text that has been previously typed in by the user. I would like to adjust the size of the div to this text. I cannot have fixed size because I dont know the length of the text. If there is no size specified div takes the width of entire window. This cause some problems for me because I am using JQuery draggable plugin and the scrollbars appear immediately when the div is dragged. Any advice on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this with css or with the style property. `<div  style="display:inline-block">  stuff </div>`

`display:inline;`   <--- for opera.

`display:inline-block;` <--- for other browsers.

You can do the browser check with javascript

something like this

```
 var divBlock=(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera')>-1)?"inline":"inline-block";
```

then set the style display option based on that variable

Keep in mind this will cause a flow like behavior so if you need a new line make sure to add `<br />` after the div

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">stuff</div>
<br />
<div style="display:inline-block">stuff 2</div>
```

OR you can use `<span></span>` instead of div

Comment: won't hurt to be prepared> i do :P

Comment: Ever heard of `window.opera`? Not that userAgent sniffing is anything to smile upon, but Opera makes it pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="myText">My Text</div>

.myText {
    display: inline;
}
```

That will change the length of the div to the width. If you want to be able to specify a minimum height and width, use inline-block:

```
.myText {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 120px; //If you want to start wrapping text at a certain width;
}
```

Comment: Also, it needs a fix to work on IE6 and IE7 http://flipc.blogspot.com/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html